# typedef enum with CGSize?

Tags: ios, objective-c, enums

I have different size of pages. I want to use enum to select size of page. somethink like that

```
 typedef NS_ENUM(CGSize, SizeType) {
    MAXSIZE=CGSizeMake(640, 1196),
    MIDIUMSIZE=CGSizeMake(320, 590),
    MINSIZE=CGSizeMake(160, 280)
};
```

its possible? if not then whats the best way to do this i need this combine value in my whole application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per the other answers, enums are basically integers, not structs.

You can just `#define` the values in a constants file:

```
#define MAXSIZE CGSizeMake(640, 1196)
#define MIDIUMSIZE CGSizeMake(320, 590)
#define MINSIZE CGSizeMake(160, 280)
```

though you might want to rename them for easier mnemonics, readability and auto-completion purposes, like:

```
#define PURPOSE_SIZE_MAX ...
#define PURPOSE_SIZE_MED ...
...
```

Comment: From my experience I would avoid `#define`s as much as possible. They're a nightmare to debug since you lose part of the type information. Why don't just use a `const`?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella, mostly succinctness. Both work obviously so it's partly a personal preference thing

Comment: A `const` definition is precisely 4 characters longer than a `#define`. I wouldn't call it a huge win, especially considering the price you pay for it.

Comment: A `const` variable in C  gets assigned memory, and it can't be used as a constant in many places. Most importantly, the compiler has to assume that the value could change, and not optimize depending on it.

Comment: Sorry @vonbrand, but I didn't quite get your remark. Care to reformulate a bit?

Answer (score 5):

An `enum` in C (and therefore in Objective-C) is a set of integer values, and that's why you cannot have `CGSize` values as members of it.

Instead, use constants. The best option is to look at what Apple does and mimic it.
If you take a look at `CGGeometry.h` you will find the definitions of various constants.

For instance, `CGSizeZero` is defined as

```
CG_EXTERN const CGSize CGSizeZero
  CG_AVAILABLE_STARTING(__MAC_10_0, __IPHONE_2_0);
```

You can then do something similar by declaring a constant in your header

```
CG_EXTERN const CGSize kMaxSize;
```

and then defining it in the implementation

```
const CGSize kMaxSize = (CGSize){ 640, 1196 };
```

---

As a bonus you can also define a type synonym for `CGSize`, for instance:

```
typedef CGSize MySizeType;
```

and then use it for declaring both constants and variables, e.g.

```
CG_EXTERN const MySizeType kMaxSize;
...
@property (nonatomic) MySizeType aSize;
```

That does't change a bit from a technical point of view, but it's semantically nicer and it basically achieves the same purpose of a `typedef enum` (which is precisely providing a convenient synonym to `int`)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot. 
The enum type is a C type and it must be integer types, each member must be the same type also. 
You can use char, BOOL, int, uint, NSInteger and so on.

For constant floating point values, you will need to declare them one by one.

structs also need to be done one by one.

Comment: Ok fine.. can you tell me the best way to do this.. i don't want to use one by one. it needs in my whole application

Comment: See above about a constants file. Or add it in your pch file.

Answer (score 2):

You can not use enum for this. In Objective C enum is inherited from C. So it is implicitly converted to int.